# Modifying Array.forEach to Automatically Set the Context to be the Caller

Tags: javascript, arrays, closures, iteration

Is it possible to create an alternate of Array.forEach that automatically sets the context "this" to be the same context as when the method was invoked?

For example (not working, not sure why):

```
Array.prototype.each = function(fn) {
    return this.forEach(fn, arguments.callee.caller);
}


function myFunction() {
    this.myVar = 'myVar';

    [1,2,3].each(function() {
        console.log(this.myVar); // logs 'myVar'
    });
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Seems like an XY problem to me...

Comment: So I don't have to remember to bind or pass "this" everytime I loop over an array

Comment: The answer is clearly "no", a JavaScript function cannot determine the value of `this` in the caller. That's why `Function.bind()` and arrow functions exist.

Comment: @WladimirPalant you should make that an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: @Kirk: There are plenty of answers already, I'm not going to repeat what other people said. For example, thefourtheye said pretty much the same thing as me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no, a JavaScript function cannot determine the value of `this` in the caller.

You can bind the function passed with the current object, like this

```
function myFunction() {
    this.myVar = 'myVar';

    [1,2,3].forEach(function() {
        console.log(this.myVar); // logs 'myVar'
    }.bind(this));
}
```

In ECMA Script 6, you can use an [Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/arrow_functions#Summary), like this

```
[1,2,3].forEach(() => {
    console.log(this.myVar); // logs 'myVar'
});
```

Comment: Ah that is the current way, I'm looking to make it automatic so I don't need to call .bind(this)

Comment: @Kirk I included a way using Arrow functions, please check. But we need ES 6 implementation.

Comment: Write your code in `typescript` and get the get the fat arrow functionality (including binding of this) automatically.  https://typescript.codeplex.com/.

Answer (score 9):

Array.forEach already takes a context argument as the optional last parameter,

```
(function() {
    this.myvar = "myvar";

    [1,2,3,4].forEach(function(v) {
        console.log("v:"+v);
        console.log("myvar="+this.myvar);
    }, this);
})();
```

See [MDN forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Also, the above examples (if we're not dealing with methods on instances regarding `this`) work without using `bind` or the optional context argument for `forEach`,  the following also works correctly:

```
function myFunction() {
    this.myVar = 'myVar';

    [1,2,3].forEach(function() {
        console.log(this.myVar); // logs 'myVar'
    });
}
myFunction();
```

Because javascript is functionally scoped, so the anonymous function can access the parent function's scope using `this` and it logs correctly.  `this` only really becomes problematic as a context when dealing with instance methods.

Comment: Ah yes, I'm trying to make this automatic so I don't need to pass in "this" as a second argument

Comment: Then, based on your previous example, if you take out the added `this` in my example, it would still log `myvar` correctly because of the context you are calling it in. Remember, javascript is functional scoped, so the anonymous function being passed to `forEach` already has access to it's parent scope, defined by `this` inside the function.  The `this` variable only becomes problematic when dealing with methods working on instances; but in the above cases, it's only function calls and scoping.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to messing with the `this` variable when passing around callbacks, you could always just assign `this` to a new variable so child scoped functions can access it:

```
Array.prototype.each = function(fn) {
    return this.forEach(fn, arguments.callee.caller);
}


function myFunction() {
    var me = this;
    me.myVar = 'myVar';

    [1,2,3].each(function() {
        console.log(me.myVar); // logs 'myVar'
    });
}
```

now you don't have to remember to pass `this` as a second parameter

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it must be pointed out that `myFunction` is a **constructor**. Yet, the first letter in the identifier is not capitalized. Please call it `MyFunction`.

If a constructor is called without the `new` operator, `this` is bound to the global object, i.e. `window` in browsers. This makes the capitalization convention our only way of spotting such mishaps.

The following lines of code demonstrate this:

```
// After the original code...
myFunction();
console.log(window.myVar); // logs "myVar"
```

Secondly, to be able to apply functions on any array, instead of changing `Array.prototype`, consider the following:

```
var utils = {array: {}};  // utils.array is a container for array utilities.
utils.array.each = function (array, func) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) { func(array[i]); }
};
utils.write = function (s) { 
    console.log(s); // Alternatively, document.write(s);
};
utils.array.each([1, 2, 3], utils.write); // prints 1 2 and 3 (on separate lines)
```

Notice that we didn't use `this` and `new`. They make JavaScript look like Java, apart from that, they rarely serve a useful purpose.

While libraries may modify `Object.prototype` and `Array.prototype`, end-developers shouldn't.

Also, we should (ideally) be able to do something like:

- `utils.array.each([1, 2, 3], console.log);` or
- `utils.array.each([1, 2, 3], document.write);`.

But most browsers won't allow it.

Hope this helped.

Comment: there's no rule that says you must capitalize the names of constructors. not everyone follows this convention, and that's perfectly fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, you are absolutely right!  
JS doesn't enforce any naming conventions. It is our duty as programmers to do that. Without it, we are more likely to accidentally call a constructor without the new keyword. Doing so is disastrous. (My answer demonstrates this.)

Comment: well, maybe. but some people and teams don't use the capitalization convention at all. that's fine. it's personal choice. you can write good code that doesn't capitalize constructor names - the most important thing is to be consistent.

Comment: @sgroves Sure. But if you expect others to read your code, wouldn't it be advisable to follow conventions. In fact, in C++ (or Python), not following the capitalization convention wouldn't be disastrous, but we still follow it. (Many of us do it intuitively.) Shouldn't we do it in JS? Not only that, it is advisable to follow all of [Douglas Crockford's JS Conventions.](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html)..... And if you will humour me, we should try to follow [LittleJ](https://github.com/sumukhbarve/jispy/blob/master/LittleJ.md) conventions.

Comment: sure. i just found it weird that it was the first thing you mentioned when it's not relevant. this could be a hobby project for all we know. the guy is free to use whatever names he wants, and is not wrong. (also sorry, i'm no fan of littlej. i actually *like* javascript, and how it works ... mostly.)

Comment: @sgroves Agreed. (Although, when it comes to JS, not being particular  with conventions seems to be a pandemic. The fact that JS is itself too permissive, only makes matters worse. I suppose this bothers me far too much than it should.)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement correctly, then you are trying to override the "this".
I think [this](http://hungred.com/how-to/tutorial-override-this-object-javascript/) can help you.